# Htaccess redirection duplication and HTML linking problem

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I'm digging all resources but cannot find the solution.

My website has multiple languages. It is basically adding ?lang=cn etc. and I'm turning it to a fake folder via htaccess with following code.

`RewriteRule ^cn/(.*) $1\?lang=cn [L,N]`

So,

`example.com/index?lang=cn`

goes to

`example.com/cn/index`

and everything is okay.

BUT, my footer links are;

`/foo/bar
/foo/bar2`

It works on English perfectly, because my English folder is the main folder, there is no /en.

When I go to Chinese and it turns to /cn, link is duplicating.

Here is what happens, when I triple click on /foo/bar

cn/foo/foo/foo/bar
I've tried to get rid of it by making the links like

../foo/bar

but this time, language folders not working.

How can I get rid of this duplication?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Main Link

```
example.com
```

Language folder

```
cn
```

Inner Link 1

```
/foo/bar
```

When you click cn and change your language it becomes,

```
example.com/cn
```

After that, click inner link 1

```
example.com/cn/foo/bar
```

Then, click inner link 1 again and it duplicates and become,

```
example.com/cn/foo/foo/bar
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This sounds like a problem you'll want to solve with PHP, and I don't think the .htaccess parts are relevant. I'd suggest removing the explanation of your rewrite rule, and only explain the problem you're having with the links.

Also, when you state that you click on `/foo/bar`, and the URL becomes `cn/foo/foo/foo/bar`, what was the URL _before_ you clicked the link? Maybe clarify that example in your question.

Just a hint: I think you are going to want to write a function that generates all of your links with PHP, accounting for the current language.

Comment: Hey there Caleb! thank you, but i think no one is gonna help about it.